# Limit by a cumulative column amount

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

Say I have a table with 3 columns:
id, row_type, row_score

I would like to select the first (or latest) rows, but limit the selection based on the cumulative score of the fetched ids

the example `table`

```
id | row_type | row_score
 1          a                  1
 2          a                  1
 3          b                  2
 4          c                  3
 5          a                  1
 6          b                  2
 7          a                  1
...
```

the result of 1st row, with a limit of a cumulative score of 4:

```
id | row_type | row_score
 1          a                  1
 2          a                  1
 3          b                  2
```

Comment: What happens if you have 1, 1, and 3? Does it stop at two rows (1+1 = 2) or 3 (1+1+3 = 5)?

Comment: good question, I would rather get more lines thab fewer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should do what you want. It uses a variable to keep a cumulative score, then uses that in a `HAVING` clause to restrict the rows returned:

```
SELECT t1.*, @cum_score := @cum_score + row_score AS cum_score
FROM table1 t1
JOIN (SELECT @cum_score := 0) c
HAVING cum_score <= 4
ORDER BY cum_score
```

Output:

```
id  row_type    row_score   cum_score
1   a           1           1
2   a           1           2
3   b           2           4
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a459e/4)

Comment: I think you mean `CROSS JOIN` ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya with no `ON` condition a `JOIN` is a `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: @Nick . . . With no `ON` condition, `JOIN` without an `ON` is a syntax error -- that MySQL happens to ignore.

Comment: @GordonLinoff MySQL specifically allows `JOIN` with no join condition in its syntax: `join_table:
table_reference [INNER | CROSS] JOIN table_factor [join_condition]` so I don't think you can really say it is ignoring a syntax error. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the desired result:

```
select t1.id, t1.row_type,t1.row_score, SUM(t2.row_score) as sum
from table t1
inner join table t2 
on t1.id >= t2.id
group by t1.id, t1.row_type,t1.row_score
having SUM(t2.row_score)<=4
order by t1.id
```

Thanks,

Rohan Hodarkar

Comment: The HAVING condition "<=4" is alternative to the limit ?

Comment: I tried that query on BigQuery and it was working for me. Can you tell me what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: The query ran, but the resultset was empty. I tested it now on the SQLfiddle @Nick built, and it works